# Segmentation Fault 11 while trying to read a text file and q sort it

Tags: c

Receiving a segmentation fault 11 while trying to read in a .txt file and q-sort it in C. This is a home work assignment for my CS class, and in it, the professor has given us a q-sort function he has written, and we need to make it faster using posix. I'm showing the relevant code here for reading in a text file, and then creating an array and using q-sort on it. The program works for an arbitrary array of strings I made up so I'm reasonably sure it's something to do with the way I am reading in the .txt file and processing it. Poem.txt is in the same directory, and the error handler works if I change the file name. Any ideas?

```
int main(){
double start, end;
double total;
char *array[100000];
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH];
int i = 0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("poem.txt", "r");
if (fp < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file to read in. | error number %d : %s \n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
// First "function" to read in a text file for sorting

while (fscanf (fp, "%s", buffer) == 1) {
    array[i] = malloc (MAX_LENGTH);
    strcpy (array[i++], buffer);
}
// printf ("%s\n", array[1]);  /* print for troubleshooting */ 
start = clock();
sortThreaded (array, i);
// freeing the memory used in the array from Malloc
for (int j = 0; array[j]; j++){
    free(array[j]);
}
end=clock();
total = (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf(" total clocks: %f\n", total);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `if (fp < 0)` should be `if (fp == NULL)` and so if the file was not opened you carried on without detecting it.

Comment: Note(2): the `free()` loop should be controlled by the number of elements allocated, not the array value, since an automatic array is not explicitly initialised to `0` (`NULL`).

Comment: `fscanf` should control the size of the buffer using special `%s` formatting. Or use `fgets`

Comment: Where's the qsort, btw ? And more to WeatherVane's point, `for (int j = 0; array[j]; j++){` should be `for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){`

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes/possibilities I see:

When checking `fp`, if the `fopen()` fails, it will be set to NULL not a negative number so that could be a source or error.

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file to read in. | error number %d : %s \n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

When you do the `fscanf` and the `strcpy()` the buffer could be overflowing, best to do a `fgets()` and a `strncpy()` and specify `MAX_LENGTH`

```
 while (fgets (buffer, MAX_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
        array[i] = malloc (MAX_LENGTH);
        strncpy (array[i++], buffer, MAX_LENGTH);
    }
```

The `free()` loop could use the same iterator `i` and decrement to be sure we are freeing everything we allocated, no more no less.

```
while (--i >= 0){
    free(array[i]);
}
```

Segmentation fault generally happens when you try to access memory that you are not allowed to access or doesn't exist. Sometimes thrown by a MPU (memory protection unit).

Answer (score 0):

First, as noted above, you should check

```
if (NULL == fp)
```

not

```
if (fp < 0)
```

Because fopen returns NULL if it can't open a file.

Second, it's unsafe to use %s in fscanf. If a input line is longer than MAX_LENGTH, you can receive a "*** stack smashing detected ***".

You can use

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

or

```
fscanf (fp, "%99999s", buffer)
```

Even though it shouldn't be the problem.

Third, array is not initialized. So, it contains garbage. In

```
for (int j = 0; array[j]; j++) {
    free(array[j]);
}
```

You may be freeing some addresses that were not allocated. As may be also the case in

```
fclose(fp);
```